# How to get last part of line with Python

Tags: python, string, macos, line

Lets say that I have prompt line:

Your MAC address is              01:23:45:67:89:ab

First part of line is always the same but last MAC address string changes all the time.

I don't know how to get address from line. If the last part is always the same I would use something like:

```
    for line in output.split("\n"):
        if line.startswith('Your MAC address is'):
            if line.endswith("01:23:45:67:89:ab"):
                 # do something
                 # do something
```

But I am lost when changeable string appears.

Comment: You want to take different actions for different mac addresses?

Comment: Yes. Something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the line using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) or [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
>>> line = 'Your MAC address is 01:23:45:67:89:ab\n'
>>> line.split()
['Your', 'MAC', 'address', 'is', '01:23:45:67:89:ab']
```

Then, get the last part:

```
>>> line.split()[-1]
'01:23:45:67:89:ab'
```

---

```
for line in output.split("\n"):
    if line.startswith('Your MAC address is'):
        addr = line.split()[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the line ends with the address use:

```
lines =output.split()
address will be lines[-1]
```